# Java - Retrieve latest/current/dynamic run value of variable of one class from another class

Tags: java

I have a .bat file which uses ANT and Java to call an xml build file, which in turn calls a target to execute two Java classes - **ClassA and ClassB in sequential order**.

In this setup:

I have classA like this:

```
public class ClassA {

private static String jobID = "initial value";


public void doSomething() {
    jobID = "1234";
    logger.info("Class A running now: Job ID current value: " + jobID);
    }
public static String getJobID() {
    return jobID;

}
```

And, I have classB like this:

```
public class ClassB {

private static String jobID = "";


public void doSomethingElse() {
    jobID = ClassA.getJobID();
    logger.info("Class B running now: Job ID retrieved from Class A is: " + jobID);
    }
}
```

I need the `doSomethingElse()` method in `ClassB` to print the `jobID` value as `"1234"` (latest current dynamic value during execution).
However, it prints the following output:

```
Class A running now: Job ID current value: 1234
Class B running now: Job ID retrieved from Class A is: initial value
```

How do I retrieve the value `"1234"` in ClassB?

Comment: Don't make the variable static for that.

Comment: I tried without static as well. But, the issue persists.

Comment: If it is not static the method getJobID() can not be static either. Share what you are doing. Include how methods are being invoked. Note that classes are not executed, methods are executed.

Comment: How are you calling those methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can make class A's **doSomething** method static and directly call it from class B where it returns job Id, as its not called so it won't show updated value.

OR

Class A's method **doSomething** is not being called from anywhere, so it won't update value.

Try making Class A's **doSomething** method static and call it from getJobID.

```
public class ClassA {
    
    private static String jobID = "initial value";
    
    
    public static void doSomething() {
        jobID = "1234";
        System.out.println("Class A running now: Job ID current value: " + jobID);
        }

    public static String getJobID() {
        doSomething();
        return jobID;
    }
  }
```

Class A running now: Job ID current value: 1234

Class B running now: Job ID retrieved from Class A is: 1234